# How to find the average CPU of a process over X amount of time in Linux

Tags: linux, process, cpu

I'm trying to find out how I can get \ calculate the CPU utilization of a specific process over X amount of time ( I write my code in python over a Linux based system ).
What I want to get for example is the average CPU of a process in the last hour\day\10 minutes...

Is there a command or a calculation I can run?
*I can't run a command like "top" in the background for X time and calculate the CPU, I need it to be in one set of commands or calculation.

- I tried top research on top command but I didn't found useful info for my case.
- ps -eo pid,ppid,cmd,%mem,%cpu --sort=-%cpu - give the average consumption on the process lifetime
- Can there be a way to use uptime or proc[pid]\stat to calculate this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

What about using pidstat?

$ pidstat -p 12345 10

Will output the stats for pid 12345 every 10 seconds. This include CPU%

From there you can run it on background, and redirect output to a file:

$ pidstat -p 12345 10 > my_pid_stats.txt &

Here is a Link with several examples. There is a lot of flexibility in the output, so you can probably customize it to better suit your needs:

https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/11/pidstat-examples/

pidstat is part of the sysstat package on ubuntu, in case you decide to install it.

Comment: Hi Ricardo, 
Thanks for the info, unfortunately in my specific situation I cant run the command on the background and check the output after X amount of time - it's for an inside tool that will run check a command result/output in on the spot and will give me the answer,
Do you know of a way I can get this info without something running all the time on the background?

Comment: The way i understand it, your very goal requires something in the background constantly checking for cpu usage in a granular enough way that you can get either daily, minute or hour averages. I do not believe you will find a default linux facility that will give you so much flexibility and so much information. i would think your best bet is to store the information (maybe each minute) in a file, and your average command can be a python function that just reads that file and averages according to an input parameter that specifies the window.